# How can I embed an CSS background image link with JSF?

Tags: css, image, jsf, jsf-2

Is there a way to create the image url dynamically for an embedded style sheet using JSF?

Example:

```
<h:head>
  <style type="text/css">
    .someId { background-image:url(images/example.jpg); }
  </style>
</h:head>
```

(using `<h:graphicImage library="images" name="logo.gif" />` is not supported for embedded CSS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understood your question:

In my project I've used this style:

```
<h1
 class="logo"
 style="background:url( #{mainMenuNavigationBean.headerImage} ) no-repeat;">
```

where `mainMenuNavigationBean` is a session bean where I set the headerImage based on some conditions.

Comment: The point is that you can just use EL in template text. But please note that using `style` attribute is considered poor practice. Using `.someId { background-image:url(#{bean.image}); }` should suffice for the OP.

Comment: @BalusC - You are right Balus but if you are using xhtml facelets, so you have different components with ui:composition you will not have the chance to put in the head this embeded css style...am I right?

Comment: Cristian, if you put it in an <h:head> tag, it should get included in the head, though i have had trouble understanding what all is allowed there.  Better yet, just externalize the css into a separate file and use the approach outlined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847473/can-i-use-el-for-external-css-files-with-jsf/6753697#6753697)