# How to render images in JSF 2.0

Tags: image, jsf, jsf-2

According to the JSF 2.0 specification, there are three ways to use h:graphicImage depending on the way by which JSF generates the "src" attribute of the HTML  tag:

```
<h:graphicImage value="#{resource['images:next.gif']}"/>

<h:graphicImage library="images" name="next.gif"/>

<h:graphicImage url="/resources/images/next.gif"/>
```

The specification states that the first two should render exactly the same markup. In my JSF implementation (MyFaces 2.0.2), here is the output HTML that is generated:

```
<img src="/AppName/faces/javax.faces.resource/next.gif?ln=images">

<img src="/AppName/faces/javax.faces.resource/next.gif?ln=images">

<img src="/AppName/resources/images/next.gif">
```

So it seems that if I use (name, library) or (value) attributes, the image is always going to be streamed to the client by JSF's servlet. If I use (url) attribute, I can give direct link to the resource with no servlet intervention.

For me, the second approach - direct server URL to resource, is faster.

In what cases the first approach - specifying (name, library) or (value) attributes, be used?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> *For me, the second approach - direct server URL to resource, is faster.*

The difference should be totally negligible. The "direct server URL to resource" approach also uses a servlet (the `default` servlet which is provided by the container). Please show your benchmark results.

---

> *In what cases the first approach - specifying (name, library) or (value) attributes, be used?*

It allows you for serving the resources from within a JAR file. It also allows you for a nicer way of dynamically switching the library in the following manner:

```
<h:graphicImage library="#{user.prefs.looknfeel}" name="next.gif"/>
```

The `library` should actually point to a common resource library with all CSS/JS/images, not to a specific "images" library.

#### Related questions:

- [How to reference JSF image resource as CSS background image url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925733/changing-the-image-of-a-hcommandbutton-using-css/6926193#6926193)
- [Changing JSF prefix to suffix mapping forces me to reapply the mapping on CSS background images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835499/changing-jsf-prefix-to-suffix-mapping-forces-me-to-reapply-the-mapping-on-css-bac/6835701#6835701)

Comment: How to set the attribute `alt` for HTML tag `img` in this case? For example `<h:graphicImage library="myPath" name="myImg" alt="myText"/>` doesn't work...

Comment: @Michael: please press `Ask Question` button on right top whenever you have new and unrelated question.

Comment: Ok no problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10897493/jsf-2-0-how-to-set-the-attribute-alt-for-image