# How to set the alt attribute for h:graphicImage?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, image, alt

I define a image in my JSF application:

```
<h:graphicImage library="myPath" name="myImg"/>
```

As result my HTML output:

```
<img src="bla-bla-bla" alt="" />
```

It works properly but I have a question. How to set the attribute `alt` for HTML tag `img` in this case? For example

```
<h:graphicImage library="myPath" name="myImg" alt="myText"/>
```

doesn't work...

Comment: Works fine for me on Mojarra 2.1.9. There's an `alt="myText"` in the generated HTML output. IIRC there was never been a bug related to this. What JSF impl/version are you using? How exactly did you conclude that it "doesn't work..."? Are you sure that you aren't confusing `alt` with `title`?

Comment: I'm sorry. You're right. Apparently my data was cached.