# ui:composition template="<template from jar>"

Tags: jsf-2, jar, facelets, el

I would like to place the Facelets template file for JSF in a JAR file.

I tried to reference it by EL as

```
<ui:composition template="#{resource['templates:template_pe_layout.xhtml']}">
```

which works perfect for CSS or images, but not for the composition template.

How could I achieve the goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `#{resource}` expression is initially designed for use **inside** CSS files only like so

```css
.someclass {
    background-image: url(#{resource['somelibrary:img/some.png']});
}
```

It's not intented for usage in `<h:outputStylesheet>`, `<h:outputScript>` or `<h:graphicImage>` which should rather be used as follows:

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="somelibrary" name="css/some.css" />
<h:outputScript library="somelibrary" name="js/some.js" />
<h:graphicImage library="somelibrary" name="img/some.png" />
```

As to the templates, just specify the full `/META-INF/resources` relative path in there.

```
<ui:composition template="/templates/template_pe_layout.xhtml">
```

#### See also:

- [Packaging Facelets files (templates, includes, composites) in a JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531432/jsf2-pages-into-a-jar)
- [Changing JSF prefix to suffix mapping forces me to reapply the mapping on CSS background images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835499/changing-jsf-prefix-to-suffix-mapping-forces-me-to-reapply-the-mapping-on-css-ba/6835701#6835701)

Comment: Thank You very much for your immediate and useful answer. Could not imagine it is so easy. When you know what to search, it can be found on other locations: [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/girgm.html). Greetings to Chichiray :-)

Comment: Additional Question: If I want to override the template in the main project, I tried to place it under <webroot>/resources/templates/template_pe_layout.xhtml, but that did not work. Is there any defined search order, if the resource is found in the main project and one or more jars? Thank You, Dieter

Comment: In local webapp, it should not be in `/resources` folder, but just directly in webroot.

Comment: Of course, must have been blind, sorry. Without `/resources`it worked.