# Obtaining Facelets templates/files from an external filesystem or database

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, resources, external, facelets

I am able to successfully get this to work with the template in my app:

```
<ui:decorate template="/WEB-INF/templates/mytemplate.xhtml">
```

I am also able to move template to `/META-INF/templates/mytemplate.xhtml` of a [JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531432/packaging-facelets-pages-in-a-jar) and get this to work:

```
<ui:decorate template="/templates/mytemplate.xhtml">
```

I would actually like to put this file onto filesystem (or database for that matter). How can I achieve this?  I found plenty of things related to `com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultResourceResolver`, but I don't think that is actually related to override the serving of the template. It is not trying resolve a URL, it is simply trying to get the file somehow on the classpath.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're already on JSF 2.2, you can do this by providing a custom [`ResourceHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/application/ResourceHandler.html) wherein you return the desired view resource in [`createViewResource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/application/ResourceHandler.html#createViewResource-javax.faces.context.FacesContext-java.lang.String-).

```
public class FaceletsResourceHandler extends ResourceHandlerWrapper {

    private ResourceHandler wrapped;

    public FaceletsResourceHandler(ResourceHandler wrapped) {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewResource createViewResource(FacesContext context, final String name) {
        ViewResource resource = super.createViewResource(context, name);

        if (resource == null) {
            resource = new ViewResource() {
                @Override
                public URL getURL() {
                    try {
                        return new File("/some/base/path", name).toURI().toURL();
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        throw new FacesException(e);
                    }
                }
            };
        }

        return resource;
    }

    @Override
    public ResourceHandler getWrapped() {
        return wrapped;
    }

}
```

Which is registered in `faces-config.xml` as below:

```
<application>
    <resource-handler>com.example.FaceletsResourceHandler</resource-handler>
</application>
```

---

Or if you're not on JSF 2.2 yet, then use [`ResourceResolver`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/view/facelets/ResourceResolver.html) instead.

```java
public class FaceletsResourceResolver extends ResourceResolver {

    private ResourceResolver parent;

    public FaceletsResourceResolver(ResourceResolver parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    @Override
    public URL resolveUrl(String path) {
        URL url = parent.resolveUrl(path); // Resolves from WAR.

        if (url == null) {
            try {
                url = new File("/some/base/path", path).toURI().toURL();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                throw new FacesException(e);
            }

        }

        return url;
    }

}
```

Which is registered in `web.xml` as below:

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_RESOURCE_RESOLVER</param-name>
    <param-value>com.example.FaceletsResourceResolver</param-value>
</context-param>
```

---

Regardless of the way, in order to provide the resource from the database, you'd either save/cache them on (temp) disk file system so you can provide the `URL` just via `File`, or invent a custom protocol such as `db://` and provide a custom [`URLStreamHandlerFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLStreamHandlerFactory.html) and [`URLStreamHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLStreamHandler.html) implementation to perform the actual job of streaming from the DB. You can find a kickoff example here [Registering and using a custom java.net.URL protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26363573/registering-and-using-a-custom-java-net-url-protocol).

Comment: Hi BalusC..This is helped get me started.  I seems to work fine with getting actual .xhtml pages.  But it doesn't seem to be working with using the template.  I edit the question to show the current error I am now getting.

Comment: The file apparently doesn't exist. Extend the kickoff example to use the `File#exists()` test and return `null` when it doesn't.

Comment: I figured out the issue...Your solution does work.  But it depends on how I define the template.  For example if I use template="myfile.xhtml" it will fail.  But if I do template="/myfile.xhtml" it will get into the ResourceResolver.