# JSF 2 application with markup content stored in a database

Tags: database, templates, jsf-2, markup

I am developing a JSF 2 application which requires markup content to be stored in a database and modified on the fly. I need some advice on how to achieve this.

I want to store some page templates (not all) in a database and have them loaded from the database rather than the exploded war file.

I have written my own custom resolver based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13292272/can-you-get-the-jsf2-uidecorate-template-xxx-outside-of-app/14622112) and can successfully load templates from a specific location on the local file system, but I need to extend this to read from the Database.

BalusC mentioned using a custom URLStreamHandlerFactory and URLStreamHandler implementation to perform the actual job of streaming from the DB, which could well be the right approach but I am not sure how to do this?

If anyone has an example, or could point me in the right direction, it would be most appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I too am interested in this.  I'll dig around and see if we can't help each other out.