# Build JSF form on-the-fly

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces, jboss

Currently I have an application (WAR) that are implementing JSF(Primefaces)+JPA+EJB3 and deployed to JBoss AS7. 
I have a new requirement from user, where: -

- User want to build their own form and upload it to the server. We had train them how to develop JSF/Primefaces XHTML forms.
- Field validation is only "mandatory field checking".
- No server down time when uploading JSF forms to the server.
- Data input from the JSF form will be inserted into DB, can be search and retrieve, and update

My solutions for the requirement above are as follows:

- Pre-build JSF managed bean with the following limitation:

  - Limit total number of input fields to maximum 20.
  - Only allow field type: input text, checkbox and radio button
  - Form action only have: Save and Cancel
- Using Facelets tamplating, in the template will contains the action buttons, CSS, JS, etc. The form body will leave out for user to compose.
- Create a extenal directory in the server, ie outside of the JBoss home, to store the uploaded user JSF form.
- Create a DB table with 20 columns plus additional audit columns, etc.
- Create an EJB SLSB for DB transactions.

QUESTIONS with reference to my solutions:

1. Is it possible to point to a JSF link outside of WAR file? Especially when using faceslet.
2. Field label need to support i18n, is it possible to upload/update i18n properties files without redeploy the app or restart the JBoss?
3. If Java classes need be created, is it possible to deploy it without restart the application? *[optional]*

Thank you.

Comment: IMO: JSF is not the tool for this job; in fact it is probably the last framework I would consider for this job (and I'm a long time supporter of JSF). But I eagerly await other responses that might amaze me.

Comment: I back Gimby's opinion.

Comment: This is not a real question. All the info until the "QUESTIONS" part is actually irrelevant to us. The three questions should each be asked in a separate question in order to be able to get detailed answers to that. Right now I can only say "Yes" to all those 3 questions because you basically asked "Is it possible?" which can only generate a Yes-No answer. Try working on that. Stack Overflow is a Question-Answer platform, not a discussion forum wherein you can continue discussing after having received the rhetorical answer. Here's an example of a good Q: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13292272

Comment: Don't understand very well, are you planning a kind of Google Forms?