# Include dynamic content containing JSF tags/components from stream

Tags: jsf-2, facelets, jsf-2.2, dynamic-content

I am working on an application where I would like to include dynamic XHTML content from a stream. To handle this I wrote a taghandler extension which dumps the dynamic XHTML content to output component as

```
UIOutput htmlChild = (UIOutput) ctx.getFacesContext().getApplication().createComponent(UIOutput.COMPONENT_TYPE);
htmlChild.setValue(new String(outputStream.toByteArray(), "utf-8"));
```

This works fine for XHTML content which has no JSF tags. If I have JSF tags in my dynamic XHTML content like `<h:inputText value="#{bean.item}"/>`, then they're printed as plain text. I want them to render as input fields. How can I achieve this?

Comment: It is ByteArrayOutputStream which was filled out by a tool from my application. This ByteArrayOutputStream contains generated xhtml content.

Comment: Does writing a JSP custom taglib will help? as i understood they are on top of the JSF lifecycle.

Comment: @BalusC does the temporary file based Resourcehandler mechanism works for <ui:include ../>? Normally resource handler is for static resources. I can't see anymore your suggested code snippet here.

Comment: Surely it works, otherwise I didn't post it as an answer. I never post untested code unless explicitly mentioned. I deleted it because this approach wasn't acceptable by you as per the comments and I couldn't tell a non-temp-file based approach with a complete working code example from top of head without investigating/testing beforehand (but theoretically, it's surely possible).

Comment: can you provide the temp file based solution here? i want to have at least a working solution in coming days. Perhaps later someone can provide a dynamic solution proposal.

Comment: I undeleted the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essentially, you should be using an `<ui:include>` in combination with a custom [`ResourceHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/application/ResourceHandler.html) which is able to return the resource in flavor of an `URL`. So when having an `OutputStream`, you should really be writing it to a (temp) file so that you can get an `URL` out of it.

E.g.

```
<ui:include src="/dynamic.xhtml" />
```

with

```
public class DynamicResourceHandler extends ResourceHandlerWrapper {

    private ResourceHandler wrapped;

    public DynamicResourceHandler(ResourceHandler wrapped) {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewResource createViewResource(FacesContext context, String resourceName) {
        if (resourceName.equals("/dynamic.xhtml")) {
            try {
                File file = File.createTempFile("dynamic-", ".xhtml");

                try (Writer writer = new FileWriter(file)) {
                    writer
                        .append("<ui:composition")
                        .append(" xmlns:ui='http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets'")
                        .append(" xmlns:h='http://java.sun.com/jsf/html'")
                        .append(">")
                        .append("<p>Hello from a dynamic include!</p>")
                        .append("<p>The below should render as a real input field:</p>")
                        .append("<p><h:inputText /></p>")
                        .append("</ui:composition>");
                }

                final URL url = file.toURI().toURL();
                return new ViewResource(){
                    @Override
                    public URL getURL() {
                        return url;
                    }
                };
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                throw new FacesException(e);
            }
        }

        return super.createViewResource(context, resourceName);
    }

    @Override
    public ResourceHandler getWrapped() {
        return wrapped;
    }

}
```

*(warning: basic kickoff example! this creates a new temp file on every request, a reuse/cache system should be invented on your own)*

which is registered in `faces-config.xml` as follows

```
<application>
    <resource-handler>com.example.DynamicResourceHandler</resource-handler>
</application>
```

---

Note: all of above is JSF 2.2 targeted. For JSF 2.0/2.1 users stumbling upon this answer, you should use `ResourceResolver` instead for which an example is available in this answer: [Obtaining Facelets templates/files from an external filesystem or database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13292272/obtaining-uidecorate-template-file-from-an-external-filesystem-or-datab/13296727#13296727). Important note: `ResourceResolver` is [deprecated](http://jdevelopment.nl/jsf-22/#809) in JSF 2.2 in favor of `ResourceHandler#createViewResource()`.

Comment: I was looking a way where we don't have to store the temp file on web server. Is there no alternative way which works directly with in memory data? Perhaps with custom jsf component/tag etc.

Comment: You can, you only need to create a custom `URLStreamHandlerFactory` and `URLStreamHandler`. Can't give examples from top of head, so no answer on that.

Comment: Question: Is it possible to access a backing bean object there and/or pass certain params to resource handler?

Comment: You can use CDI `@Inject` in resource handlers or programmatically evaluate EL by `Application#evaluateExpressionGet()`. Passing params is of course possible "the usual way" by manipulating the `src` accordingly like so `src="/dynamic.xhtml?param=value"`, you only have to parse it yourself using e.g. `String#split()` on `resourceName`. Note that the format of path in `src` is completely free to your choice. E.g. `src="dynamic:foo,bar,baz"` etc in combination with a `if (resourceName.startsWith("dynamic:"))` check.

Comment: I tried with this and it works as expected. But i was unable to @Inject my bean there. Is there anything special we need here to inject a bean?

Comment: I solved this with URLStreamHandlerFactory and URLStreamHandler. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My solution for JSF 2.2 and custom URLStream Handler

```java
public class DatabaseResourceHandlerWrapper extends ResourceHandlerWrapper {

    private ResourceHandler wrapped;

    @Inject
    UserSessionBean userBeean;

    public DatabaseResourceHandlerWrapper(ResourceHandler wrapped) {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    @Override
    public Resource createResource(String resourceName, String libraryName) {
        return super.createResource(resourceName, libraryName); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public ViewResource createViewResource(FacesContext context, String resourceName) {
        if (resourceName.startsWith("/dynamic.xhtml?")) {
            try {
                String query = resourceName.substring("/dynamic.xhtml?".length());
                Map<String, String> params = splitQuery(query);
                //do some query to get content
                String content = "<ui:composition"
                        + " xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:ui='http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets'"
                        + " xmlns:h='http://java.sun.com/jsf/html'> MY CONTENT"
                        + "</ui:composition>";

                final URL url = new URL(null, "string://helloworld", new MyCustomHandler(content));
                return new ViewResource() {
                    @Override
                    public URL getURL() {
                        return url;
                    }
                };
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new FacesException(e);
            }
        }

        return super.createViewResource(context, resourceName);
    }

    public static Map<String, String> splitQuery(String query) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        Map<String, String> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        String[] pairs = query.split("&");
        for (String pair : pairs) {
            int idx = pair.indexOf("=");
            params.put(URLDecoder.decode(pair.substring(0, idx), "UTF-8"), URLDecoder.decode(pair.substring(idx + 1), "UTF-8"));
        }
        return params;
    }

    @Override
    public ResourceHandler getWrapped() {
        return wrapped;
    }

    static class MyCustomHandler extends URLStreamHandler {

        private String content;

        public MyCustomHandler(String content) {
            this.content = content;
        }

        @Override
        protected URLConnection openConnection(URL u) throws IOException {
            return new UserURLConnection(u, content);
        }

        private static class UserURLConnection extends URLConnection {

            private String content;

            public UserURLConnection(URL url, String content) {
                super(url);
                this.content = content;
            }

            @Override
            public void connect() throws IOException {
            }

            @Override
            public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
                return new ByteArrayInputStream(content.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            }
        }

    }

}
```