# How to modify <ui:include> to render dynamically generated content passed as a bean property

Tags: jsf, facelets

I have a requirement to dynamically create content and then include it in an already existing page I thought of using the the ui:include tag but the tag expects its source to be an already existing file.[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20268860/include-dynamic-content-containing-jsf-tags-components-from-stream/20269772#20269772) deals with a simillar scenario but the answers involve creating a temporary file.Is it possible to modify the tag so the src attribute can be set to a bean property instead of a file?
eg:

```
< ui:include src=#{bean.htmlToRender} />
```

**JSF version 2.2** (mojarra)

Comment: You need re-render page after change (which was in region included via `ui:include`)

Comment: Sure it does. Have you tried it?