# Render JSF tags fetched from database

Tags: database, jsf, facelets

I am trying o create a dynamic component that fetches the content from the a database a writes the content to the page. I am using

```
 ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
 writer.write(content)
```

This renders the html tags fine but when I use JSF tags such as h:input or ui:fragment and so on it does not evaluate them it just writes the raw output to the page. Is there a way around this? I tried the solution in [Include dynamic content containing JSF tags/components from stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20268860/include-dynamic-content-containing-jsf-tags-components-from-stream?rq=1) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32570134/jsf2-java-response-writer-to-render-facelets-tags (where @BalusC said it would take more than a couple of paragraphs to explain). Any help would be great.

Comment: You'd better take a step back and do it during view build time, not during view render time. Here's a clue (and possible duplicate question): http://stackoverflow.com/q/13292272

Comment: This would be dynamic content fetched from content management databased based on user login

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Obtaining Facelets templates/files from an external filesystem or database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13292272/obtaining-facelets-templates-files-from-an-external-filesystem-or-database)