# Display html files uploaded by users

Tags: html, jsf-2

I am writing an application where users can upload a zip file that contains html files.

How can I show those html files in my JSF views?

I am using wildlfy and I upload the files and unzip them to a folder in the wildfly standalone/data directory. The zip files contains a file that contains an html menu, a folder containing the html files (which are just html documents containing divs).

Right now, in my JSF view, I only display a link to that uploaded folder. When the user clicks on the link, the index.html file of that folder is displayed.

I would like, however, to be able to incorporate the html menu into my jsf view and then display the html files in my JSF view when the link pointing to them is clicked.

Also,  the html menu includes an text input field that I want to use for a full text search in the uploaded html files.

So I need to be able to get the value of that text field in my backing bean.

Should I use `<iframe src="#{bean.iframeUrl}"></iframe>`  for this or is there a better solution?

So in essence: Can I incorporate the uploaded files into my JSF views and thus communicate between the uploaded html files and my backing beans?

**EDIT**

According to  Kukeltje's comment and the post I think I need to to this:

In the JSF view where the links to the folders are displayed, I create a ui:insert for the menu and a ui:insert for the html pages to be loaded when I click on the links in the menu.

And the loading of the pages should be implemented using a custom Resource handler.

So I onyl need to stream the menu once and then when I click on a link in the menu, I stream the html page I want to display, correct?

And I doing it this way I can could other JSF tags around the streamed input, as well, and I can communicate between the streamed html files and my backing beans?

Comment: Can the file contain jsf tags, then try the answer in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20268860/include-dynamic-content-containing-jsf-tags-components-from-stream. If not, try to use the code in the question of that answer

Comment: The post is a bit beyond me, could you read my edit and tell me if I understood the post correctly?

Comment: interpretation seems correct