# Default .xhtmls with JSF if don't exist a specific

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a website with two diferents styles (some different xhtml files). I would like have three folders:

- common
- style1
- style2

When a user is logged, he select one style, then, JSF load the files from this style, but if the file don't exist in style's folder, load the default file from common folder

- common

  - file1.xhtml
  - file2.xhtml
  - file3.xhtml
- style1

  - file2.xhtml
  - file3.xhtml
- style2

  - file1.xhtml

If the user select style1, he loads file2.xhtml and file3.xhtml from style1, and file1.xhtml from common.

Any idea?

I use JSF with Primefaces 6.0

Comment: Although you use PrimeFaces, this is not a PrimeFaces related question but a pure JSF one

Comment: A resource handler might be useful here. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13292272/obtaining-facelets-templates-files-from-an-external-filesystem-or-database

Comment: I start work with Resource Handler. I think that it will work ;)