# Adding CDI beans archive from jboss module on the fly

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, wildfly-10, jboss-modules

I am building a JEE plugin architecture using wildfly (and jboss modules which included by wildfly core).

currently i got working loading xhtml from other deployed modules (core-web.war loads xhtml files from `deployment.customers.jar` or any `deployment.xmodule.jar`) thanks to [Obtaining Facelets templates/files from an external filesystem or database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13292272/obtaining-facelets-templates-files-from-an-external-filesystem-or-database) and a "extension registry" i use to know which modules are available.

The problem arises when i try to use managed beans from those deployed modules, this because annotations are not scanned, i don't know if this is because i need a custom component on JSF, EL, Classpath, CDI or Jboss Module.

I am using Wildfly 10, JEE 7, primefaces 6.

whats the simplest way to get this working.

Some of my tries are:

1. i have read jboss modules documentation, i found a module dependencies can't be modified after module is initialized. But i found i can access any module programatically. for instance:

   ```
   Module currentMod = org.jboss.modules.Module.getCallerModule();
   Module otherModule = currentMod.getModuleLoader().loadModule(ModuleIdentifier.create("deployment.inmuebles-web.jar"));
   otherModule.getClassLoader().loadClass("co.hatit.enterprise.inmuebles.beans.InmueblesBean");
   ```
2. i have read CDI doc and it says i can listen lifecycle events such
   as type and bean discovery, but i'm not sure if this is what i need.

   ```
   public void beforeBeanDiscovery(@Observes BeforeBeanDiscovery bbd, BeanManager beanManager) {
       try {

           Field f = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("classes");
           f.setAccessible(true);

           //Get all classes from other module
           ClassLoader classLoader = org.jboss.modules.Module.getCallerModule().getModuleLoader()
                   .loadModule(org.jboss.modules.ModuleIdentifier.create("deployment.customers-web.jar"))
                   .getClassLoader();
           List<Class> classes = (List<Class>) f.get(classLoader);

           for (Class<?> clazz : classes) {
               final AnnotatedType<?> annotatedType = beanManager.createAnnotatedType(clazz);
               bbd.addAnnotatedType(annotatedType);
           }
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   ```

   3. i also tried to build a custom el resolver, but it's not working.

      ```
      public class PluginELResolver extends ELResolver {

          @Override
          public Object getValue(ELContext ctx, Object base, Object property) {
              return CDI.current().getBeanManager().getBeans("inmueblesBean");
          }
      }
      ```

Comment: CDI is CDI and in that way JSF cannot load CDI modules or similar. Hence not JSF related

Comment: sorry @Kukeltje, but i don't undertand too much if is there some i can do to achieve this.

Comment: How do you add dependencies to the other deployments to your deployment?

Comment: i use a jboss-deployment-structure.xml file