# Background url path in a jsf template

Tags: css, jsf

i'm in trouble here. I have a JSF application that has a template file called **baseTemplate.xhtml**. This file is located in /resources/template folder. Follows the file code:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="default.css"/>
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="cssLayout.css"/>
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="menu.css"/>
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="rodape.css"/>
        <title>JSF Project</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <div id="estrutura">
            <div class="top">
                <ui:insert name="top">
                    <ui:include src="somefile"/>
                </ui:insert>
            </div>
            <div id="menu">
                <ui:insert name="menu">
                    <ui:include src="somefile"/>
                </ui:insert>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div id="left">
                    <ui:insert name="left">
                    </ui:insert>
                </div>
                <div id="content" class="left_content">
                    <ui:insert name="content"></ui:insert>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="bottom">
                <ui:insert name="bottom">
                    <ui:include src="somefile"/>
                </ui:insert>
            </div>
        </div>    
      </h:body>
</html>
```

In my **cssLayout.css** file, located inside /resources/css folder, i have the following rule:

```
.top {
   position: relative;
   height: 120px;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0 0 15px 0;
   background-image: url('imgSite/sisLogo.png');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

The image sisLogo.png is located under /resources/css/imgSite. All pages from my app are inside **/pages**. When i use the template, he doesn't load the image background for **top**, but other css properties are loaded. Seems to be a background-image url path problem. How i could solve this?

The project folder structure is as follows:

```
/
 pages/
     home.xhtml (using the template)
 resources/
     css/
         cssLayout.css
         imgSite/
             sisLogo.png
     templates/
         baseTemplate.xhtml
```

Comment: Look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835499/changing-jsf-prefix-to-suffix-mapping-forces-me-to-reapply-the-mapping-on-css-ba/6835701#6835701

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CSS background images are loaded relative to the **request URL** of the CSS file (and thus not immediately relative to its physical location in the web content). If you explore the generated HTML output of the `<h:outputStylesheet>`, then you'll see that the request URL has become different. Assuming a context path of `/somecontext` and a `FacesServlet` mapping of `*.xhtml`, it'll look like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/somecontext/javax.faces.resource/cssLayout.css.xhtml?ln=css" />
```

Note that your ([improper btw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used)) usage of the `library` has moved the `/css` to `?ln=css`. You'd need to fix the background image `url()` accordingly so that it's properly relative to the real request URL of the CSS. E.g.

```css
background-image: url("../resources/css/imgSite/sisLogo.png");
```

A more reliable way, which takes JSF resource identifier rules and `FacesServlet` mapping into account, is to use `#{resource}` in EL:

```css
background-image: url("#{resource['css:imgSite/sisLogo.png']}");
```

#### See also:

- [Changing JSF prefix to suffix mapping forces me to reapply the mapping on CSS background images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835499/changing-jsf-prefix-to-suffix-mapping-forces-me-to-reapply-the-mapping-on-css-ba/6835701#6835701)
- [What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used)

Comment: How are those EL expressions like `#{resource['css:imgSite/sisLogo.png']}` in **external CSS files** parsed? Are CSS files themselves parsed along with XHTML files (from top to bottom)? Is this else done somewhat magically? I do by far, envision a different thing in case of **external JavaScript files** in which neither XML special characters are required to be escaped nor the code in those files needs to be enclosed in ugly `CDATA` tag(s) -  because the code in external JavaScript files is simply included in the generated HTML - the files themselves are not parsed. Is it?

Comment: @Tiny: it isn't supported on external CSS files. It's only supported on internal CSS files, served by the same webapp. It isn't supported in JS files in any way (although it'd have been nice as well). EL evaluating is done via a special input stream reader which recognizes `#{..}` and then evaluates them via the current faces context. Note that the presence of EL in  a CSS file is checked only once per CSS file applicationwide. If no EL is found in CSS, then JSF will continue to read it the regular way.

Comment: @BalusC is there any way to point to folder as a whole, not a single file? I am having trouble with MarkClusterer from Google Developers, one of its options points to a folder where images are, and I don't know how to do that I tried  "#{resource['img:m']}" where **img** and **m** are folders

Answer (score 0):

Your case is simple. I copy it :

```
/
 pages/
     home.xhtml (using the template)
 resources/
     css/
         cssLayout.css
         imgSite/
             sisLogo.png
     templates/
         baseTemplate.xhtml
```

***Small pertinent advice*** : ***when you do not know*** how to use relative path or ***when you have problem to implement it***, simply use ***absolute path***. ***Absolute paths*** have the powerful advantage in some cases ***to be mesured from the root***. So they are more simple.

In your case, regardless of the structure, you can do this :

***/Name of your project/PathToTheImage***

Exemple :(Let's suppose your project is called ***"NewYork"***. It's just a name! You should do)

***/NewYord/resources/css/imgSite/sisLogo.png***

I suppose you know that you have to include the css path in the jsf code.

Exemple : (in your case, you have to put this in your code xhtml who need this css)

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="cssLayout.css" />
```

hope help.

Thanks