# Images from the resources directory are not located in a CSS file

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2.2

I have a resources folder on the webapp root. I placed a CSS file named `screen.css` under `resources->login->css` and images to be used in styles available in the CSS file are placed unded `resources->login->css->images` as can be seen in the [following picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEqYk.png).

[image]

Therefore, an image should be accessible from styles available in the `screen.css` CSS file as follows.

```css
background: url(images/login_bg.jpg) no-repeat top center;
```

I set the `url` attribute everywhere in the `screen.css` file but no images from the `images` folder are available to the browser.

What is missing here?

---

I have done it using the following resource evaluation expression.

```
background: url("#{resource['login:css/images/login_bg.jpg']}") no-repeat top center;
```

But why does giving the `url` attribute a path relative to the given CSS file `screen.css` does not work in the first case.

Comment: Your question has been thoroughly answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166854/background-url-path-in-a-jsf-template

Comment: And can be solved with http://showcase.omnifaces.org/resourcehandlers/UnmappedResourceHandler

Comment: @BalusC : May please close the question as a duplicate.