# Redirect CSS URL to one without www subdomain

Tags: css, jsf, url-rewriting, glassfish, prettyfaces

I would like to know if there is a way to remove www (or add) when happens a request.

Here's my problem:

I'm inserting CSS this way: "//domain.com.br/resources/cssname.css"

if I access a page http, everything works perfectly, but when I access a page https USING "www.domain.com.br" the page doesn't load CSS files

if I insert CSS like this: "//WWW.domain.com.br/resources/cssname.css" the oposite happens, and when i access a page using "domain.com.br" there is no css.

Could I change all requests when using remove wwww or all request add www?

I saw that prettyfaces has  could that be done using this?

Also, I'm using glassfish, I don't know if this can be done by there or by provider.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I always use:

```
#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/cssname.css
```

As the path to any of my resources.
This way, I am sure that I am always getting the right path to my resource.

Hope this helps
Cheers

Comment: It worked man. Thanks. 
Actually, I've changed the <link> to <h:outputStyleSheet> But in some places I need to use #facesContex.externalContext.requestContextPath}/images

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should not be worrying about the domain name nor the context path in all your CSS/JS/image resources at all.

Instead of

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//domain.com/context/resources/style/some.css" />
<script src="//domain.com/context/resources/script/some.js"></script>
<img src="//domain.com/context/resources/images/some.png" />
```

or even

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="#{request.contextPath}/resources/style/some.css" />
<script src="#{request.contextPath}/resources/script/some.js"></script>
<img src="#{request.contextPath}/resources/images/some.png" />
```

or even the clumsily longer as suggested by other answer

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/style/some.css" />
<script src="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/script/some.js"></script>
<img src="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/images/some.png" />
```

you should *actually* be using

```html
<h:outputStylesheet name="style/some.css" />
<h:outputScript name="script/some.js" />
<h:graphicImage name="images/some.png" />
```

And, for CSS background images, instead of

```css
.some {
    background-image: url("../images/some.png");
}
```

you should *actually* be using

```css
.some {
    background-image: url("#{resource['images/some.png']}");
}
```

#### See also:

- [How to reference CSS / JS / image resource in Facelets template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367421/how-to-reference-resource-in-facelets-template/8368727#8368727)
- [What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used)
- [Changing JSF prefix to suffix mapping forces me to reapply the mapping on CSS background images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835499/changing-jsf-prefix-to-suffix-mapping-forces-me-to-reapply-the-mapping-on-css-ba/6835701#6835701)

Comment: Thanks @Balusc, I've made this. 
I have some doubts: 
    url("#{resource['images/some.png']}");

About this resource, it's the folder 'resource' in the project? Which has js, cs, img, etc?

Also, is it possible to do in jquery, for example?

Another thing is:
     <h:graphicImage name="/images/some.png" />

Instead of
          <h:graphicImage name="images/some.png" />

isn't it?

Thanks again, I've learned a lot with your answers here.