# Can't link to images from CSS in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee

I am having CSS using the resources folder in JSF and two sub-folders named css and images. I am trying to use some images as background in the css by writing `background-image:url('../images/myImage.png');` but it does not work. This is what I use to load the CSS on the page:

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="screen.css" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use el expressions in your css as long as your WAR structure includes the resources folder under which you have your css folder.  See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847473/can-i-use-el-for-external-css-files-with-jsf/6753697#6753697).

In short, this:

```
.someClass {
    background-image: url('#{resource['images/image1.png']}');
}
```

Or something similar