# load css and js file in JSF

Tags: jsf-2.2

I am trying to load the css and js files as well as the image in the `img` directory from  `mainStyle.css` but without secuss. I can not load the js file and the `obama.jpg` from the css stylesheet.

I am facing a problem to explain why am I getting  `Hell World! Say apple!` green? I have set them before green but now they have the red value, despite that I am getting them rendered in green!!.

**index.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="htpp://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:head>
    <title>External resources</title>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="mainStlye.css" />
    <h:outputScript library="js" name="mainJS.js" /> 
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h1>Using external resources</h1>

        <div class="message">Hello World!</div>

        <div class="message">Say apple!</div>

</h:body>
</html>
```

**mainStyle.css**

```
body{
    background: url("#{resource['img/obama.jpg']}");
}

.message{
    color:red;

}
```

**mainJS.js**

```
alert('Javascript works fine');
```

[image]

Comment: have a look on : http://stackoverflow.com/a/11988418/1460591

Comment: Open the page in a real browser and see what's being loaded. The green colour text means something else going on with your project (it can't be achieved only with the files you posted).

Comment: @XtremeBiker: Oh thanks it works in the real browser!! The text is red but the image is not being loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the relative path of the image in the css.
Furthermore, you wrote background instead of background-image.

Have a look here:
[Can I use EL for external CSS files with JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847473/can-i-use-el-for-external-css-files-with-jsf)

In your case, would be:

```
body{
   background-image: url(../img/obama.jpg);
}
```